# Historical Weather Data for every Country in the World

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, geodesy

I am trying to create a list of the average global temperatures per-year for the last 18 years using the `WeatherData` function. You can input a set coordinates followed by `"Temperature"` and a date to get the historical data. I am trying to do this for every country in the world. Here is my code:

```
 YearlyGlobalTemp = 
 WeatherData[#, 
 "Temperature", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2018, 1, 1}, "Year"}] & /@ 
 CountryData["Countries"];
```

I should be getting a list of `timeseries` plots for my output, but instead I get a list of 240 `$Failed`.

Comment: Your code seems to be working for me.  After evaluating `YearlyGlobalTemp` is a list of 240 `TimeSeries` objects, which I can apply `DateListPlot` to.  What do you get as output?

Comment: My output of `YearlyGlobalTemp`, I get a list of 240 `$Failed.` What does your output look like?

Comment: I get a list of `TimeSeries`.  The first step here is to work with a list of just 2 countries, so you don't have to wait 10 minutes to see that it failed.  Also, we can try clearing any cached values you might have.  Try evaluating ```Internal`ClearEntityValueCache[];
countries = CountryData["Countries"][[;; 3]];
WeatherData[GeoPosition[#], 
   "Temperature", {{2000, 1, 1}, {2018, 1, 1}, "Year"}] & /@ countries```

Comment: @hwhorf Did the comment by JasonB or your own efforts solved your problem? You could post your own answer!